# How to measure DynamoDB table's time required to write an item when it is configured to be eventually consistent

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, metrics, consistency, eventual-consistency

Does DynamoDB publish a metric that can help track eventually consistent write operations?
If not, what are some effective strategies to measure such a phenomenon?